# Why is `last` showing so many logins in one second? Did I got hacked?

Tags: login, security, users, last-command

When I ran `last` into the terminal, I found this:

```
roundduc pts/0        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:47   still logged in   
roundduc :0           :0               Sun Nov 15 16:46   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-33-generi Sun Nov 15 16:46 - 16:48  (00:01)    
roundduc pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:44 - 16:45  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/8        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:37 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:37 - 16:39  (00:02)    
roundduc pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:37 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/71       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/70       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/69       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/68       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/67       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/66       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/65       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/64       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/63       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/62       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/61       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/60       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/59       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/58       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/57       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/56       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/55       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/54       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/53       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/52       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/51       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/50       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/49       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/48       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/47       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/46       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/45       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/44       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/43       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/42       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/41       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/40       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/39       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/38       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/37       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/36       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/35       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/34       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/33       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/32       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/31       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/30       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/29       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/28       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/27       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/26       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/25       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/24       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/23       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/14       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/13       :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/8        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 15 16:36 - 16:37  (00:00)    
roundduc :0           :0               Sun Nov 15 16:33 - down   (00:11)
```

Look how many logins of mine happened in the span of a SECOND. I remember changing GRUB's theme, but I don't think that's really the cause here. I'm worried I got hacked, especially with all those logins happening at Nov 15, 16:36 (4:36 PM).

Comment: It looks like a bunch of terminal windows were started and closed quickly - note that all of them were from `:0` - the GUI, and none were initiated remotely. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: Oh, that's why, oops. :P I remember being stupid by spamming ctrl+alt+t, being a goofball. Heh heh heh....... :P

Comment: ok, sorry about that

Comment: NP. Fun problem. :D

Comment: Linux is love, Linux is life.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found out it was due to me being a goofball opening terminals with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I wasn't hacked.